# Model Binder Performance for Nullable Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there any reason why it takes much more time to retrieve nullable types posted to a controller action?

Here is a simple case I've put together.

The form:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new {  }))
{
    IList<int> integers = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        integers.Add(5*i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < integers.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => integers[i]);
    }
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now the controller's action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(IList<int> integers)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < integers.Count; i++)
    {
        Response.Write("integers[" + i + "] = " + integers[i] + "<br />");
    }
    return Content("DONE");
}
```

On my dev. machine Chrome indicates that it waits for the server response for about 500 ms.

If "MyAction" expects a list of nullable integers it takes 2500 ms.

Here is signature of the slow action :

```
public ActionResult TestDouble(IList<int?> integers)
```

Is this normal? Is there a way to speed things up if I need a nullable type to be posted?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?  How many times did you run the performance test for each case?  I wouldn't trust anything under 10 runs for each.

Comment: MVC 4 with .NET 4.5 - Runned multiple times. Always the same result. I also noticed that when using nullable types I see first chance exceptions in my debug output. (A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll).

Comment: Have you tried running the same test with the code compiled to release mode?  Perhaps its the monitoring of those exceptions by the IDE in debug mode that is adding the performance overhead.

Comment: I tested this code on my machine. Ints took 7ms and nullable ints took 20ms. Nullable does add a bit of overhead, but why are your times so high in the first place?

Comment: I realized there were a few expensive lines of code in my Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute which was the cause of most of the 500 ms delay for non nullable ints. I also disabled DevExpress' model binder and gained an extra 60 ms. Now the results are 25 ms for non nullable ints and about 1500 ms for nullable ints. Debug or release config has no impact.

Comment: @RowanFreeman Do you see first chance exceptions clogging your debug output when you post nullable ints? During the 1.5 second of wait I see InvalidCastException popping in there.

Comment: After testing over and over again (now in a completely empty solution) I get the same result. Very fast for classic ints, extremely slow for the same data if the action expects nullable values.